# Why can't perl debugger find module that script finds?

Tags: linux, perl, debugging, cpan, fedora

Using CPAN, I've installed GD::Graph to make horizontal stacked bar charts. CPAN installed the modules in /root/.cpan/build/GD-2.45-4PSn9K, which is not in @INC. In my script, I'm able to access the modules by adding

```
use lib "/root/.cpan/build/GD-2.45-4PSn9K"
```

The script now generates the charts with no problems. I wanted to use the perl debugger ("perl -d myscript.pl") but it complains about not being able to find GD.pm (which is in that path). I added the path to PERL5LIB, verified with "perl -V", but still the debugger can't find it.

Perhaps one way around this is to have GD installed in one of the @INC paths, but a) I don't know how to do that, and b) I really would like to understand what's going on.

This is on Fedora Core 12.

I don't know if if makes a difference, but GD::Graph is actually used in a module which is included by my main script. The main script does not use it.

Update: Following suggestions below, I re-entered CPAN and forced the installation. CPAN said it found the installation at /root/.cpan/ (etc) and pre-pended that path to @INC. I then manually deleted GD from the .cpan directory and went to install again. This time CPAN put it in the same place, and also in /usr/local/lib/perl5/GD-2.45PSn9K". It prepended both paths to @INC. I've verified that it's there, and the perl debugger claims to be looking there, but *still* cannot find GD.pm (which *is* there) and won't run the script.

```
@INC:
 /usr/local/lib/perl5/GD-2.45-4PSn9K/
  (and others)
```

From perl -d:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module GD in @INC (@INC contains:
```

... and lists that path among its others. It really is there:

```
[root /]# find . -name "GD.pm"
./usr/local/lib/perl5/GD-2.45-4PSn9K/GD.pm
./usr/local/lib/perl5/GD-2.45-4PSn9K/blib/lib/GD.pm
 (and the /root/.cpan paths)
```

Comment: that's a CPAN build directory, it should have also installed the files somewhere in `PERL5LIB`.  CPAN lists the directories it installed files to at the end of the build

Comment: You could also try 'perldoc -lm GD::Graph' to find the installed location.

Answer (score 1):

On bourne-compatible:

```
export PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/root/.cpan/build/GD-2.45-4PSn9K
```

This isn't the best solution. You should actually install this via `cpan`. If it's working fine and won't install, then you might need to `force` it.

```
force install GD::Graph
```

And there is also

```
perl -I/root/.cpan/build/GD-2.45-4PSn9K -d myscript.pl
```

Comment: @jasper77: It probably failed a test or bolted on some not-too-robust condition the release developer put in.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use that location - `cpan` will probably throw it away soon (as Eric mentioned in his comment, that's just a build directory, and these get cleaned away after a while).

If you can access it from your script without that `use lib` line you can find the other (presumably properly installed) version by

```
use GD;
warn $INC{"GD.pm"};
```

or look at the @INC paths to see potential places it might be hiding

```
warn join, "\n", @INC;
```

Snoopy's `perldoc lm` trick is good too, but might not be completely accurate if you have other things playing with @INC in the script.

If you do need that `use lib` line to get it to work in the script version, then presumably it wasn't installed properly so Axeman's `force install` suggestion could be worth a shot (and that should tell you where it is putting the files).

Comment: Forcing the installation only caused the /root/.cpan location to be prepended to PERL5LIB, instead of installing it at a different location. So I removed it from there and tried the installation again, this time forcing it. CPAN put it back in the same place. If cpan will throw that location away, what can I do?